# Using a conditional to change a whole column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL question that seems to be alluding me. My table looks something like this:

```
Date          Equipment_ID     Condition
2013-01-01        1               Good
2013-01-01        2               Good
2013-01-01        3              unused
2013-01-02        1              unused
2013-01-02        2               good
2013-01-02        3               good
2013-01-03        1              unused
2013-01-03        2              unused
2013-01-03        3              unused
```

What I need to do is add another column Equipment_Used. This column will say 'Yes' or 'No'. The conditions are that for a date cycle if all three are unused the Equipment_Used will be 'No' for all three and if even of of the conditions for the date cycle has good then all three will be 'Yes'. I understand if I use:

```
UPDATE my_Table
  SET Equipment_Used =
    CASE Condition
      WHEN 'unused' THEN 'No'
      ELSE 'Yes'
    END
```

this will set individual elements to yes or no But I want to group them by Date and only use the conditional I set up. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes it is MS sql server.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you already have created the new column and filled it with 'no', the following should work:

```
update yourTable t1
   set Equipment_Used = 'yes'
 where exists (
       select 1
         from yourTable t2
        where t1.Date = t2.Date
          and t2.condition = 'good'
);
```

You set the Equipment_Used to 'yes' if there's any item which is good that day; at least that's the way I understand your question

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does the trick - Assuming you meant :

> and if even **ONE** of the conditions for the date cycle has good then
>   all three will be 'Yes'

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        EquipmentId, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Condition = 'unused' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UnusedCount
    FROM Equipment
    GROUP BY EquipmentId
)
UPDATE e
  SET e.Equipment_Used =
    CASE cte.UnusedCount
      WHEN 3 THEN 'No'
      ELSE 'Yes'
    END 
FROM Equipment e 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cte 
    ON e.EquipmentID = cte.EquipmentID;
```

[Sql Fiddle is back up again](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90214/3)

Comment: Thanks this worked great with a few tweaks. I actually changed the update to look for good then add and the update updated when the sum is 0 that way if they change the amount of records per date it doesn't break. Thanks for the help.